# Custom Background by Page IDs

Tags: php, customization, css, child-theme, custom-background

I use TwentyTwent theme and want to change its background colour by page IDs.

I'm not sure but when I check the functions.php, I see below lines which are related to background colours:

```php
    // Custom background color.
    add_theme_support(
        'custom-background',
        array(
            'default-color' => 'f5efe0',
        )
    );

    // Add the background option.
    $background_color = get_theme_mod( 'background_color' );
    if ( ! $background_color ) {
        $background_color_arr = get_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
        $background_color     = $background_color_arr[0]['default-color'];
    }
    $editor_color_palette[] = array(
        'name'  => __( 'Background Color', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'slug'  => 'background',
        'color' => '#' . $background_color,
    );
```

Is there any simple way to change the background colour according to Page's ID?

Regards.

Comment: How will you know which colour? Is it random? Or being stored in post meta?

Comment: @TomJNowell I normally set the default background colour (#f5efe0) in the customization settings. However, I would like to change that colour into white (#ffffff) by Page IDs. (Actually trying to change it for 8 or 9 pages only if it is possible.)

Comment: If you know the IDs/slugs and know they will never change, this can be done with CSS alone, no PHP or JS changes needed, by using the page specific CSS classes added to the body tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS is generated on the file `inc/custom-css.php`, the background color is set on line **76**:

`$background = sanitize_hex_color_no_hash( get_theme_mod( 'background_color' ) );`

So you can take advantage of the [`theme_mod_{$name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/) filter, which changes the value of the `get_theme_mod($name)` function, by adding this to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter(
    'theme_mod_background_color',
    function( $value ) {
        $custom_bg_page_ids = array( 18, 19, 20 );
        $custom_bg_color = 'ca2d2d';
        global $post;
        if ( in_array( $post->ID, $custom_bg_page_ids ) ) {
            return $custom_bg_color;
        }
        return $value;
    }
);
```

Comment: This will not work as there is no global $post value set at this moment.

Comment: Although my website is WP multi-site, this solution works well! Thank you both @Himad and Vitauts Stočka for your help! Appreciate that!

Comment: @VitautsStočka The global var `$post`  is set before this filter call, which means that it'll be already defined.

Comment: @Himad For some reason on my test server '$post' it is not set at this point. Tried this solution myself as well as copied your code. But if it works for you - fine.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can use something like this

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() {
    $post = get_post();
    if ($post && $post->ID == ... do your post selection here) {
        ?>
        <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff !important;
        }
        </style>
        <?php

    }
});
```